# In Excel VBA, how to copy a picture between 2 sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I'm trying to copy picture from sheet "membership Form" to sheet "members", but picture is not copying to specific location (row 146, col 24). Target address is selecting but not copying. Code is working till `historyWks.Cells(146, 24).Select` but 'paste' is not working?

```
Sub copypasttest()
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim historyWks As Worksheet

  Set inputWks = Worksheets("membership Form")
  Set historyWks = Worksheets("members")
  Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
  inputWks.Activate
  inputWks.Range("M3").Select
  Selection.Cut
  historyWks.Activate
  historyWks.Cells(146, 24).Select
  historyWks.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: this code is a part group of codes in a project. in that project, it is not working along with my project but it is working when i tested seperatly

Comment: error is showing at 'paste' line in the code ie.,   "    historyWks.Paste.  "                                                                  i'm new to excel VBA, so please help.

Comment: Have you tried Selection.Copy instead of Selection.Cut?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
Sub copypastetest()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsHist As Worksheet

  Set wsInput = Worksheets("membership Form")
  Set wsHist = Worksheets("members")
  wsInput.Pictures(1).Copy               'Assuming it is the first picture
  wsHist.Cells(146,24).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for reply and your code is usefull to me. i want to copy the picture from specific range, so i used  '  inputWks.Range("M3").CopyPicture  ' this line. every thing is ok but that picture is not deselecting after past, even after using '  Application.CutCopyMode = False  ' line. so could you please solve this issue ?